# Why does an element of an array assigned to a variable changes when the variable is changed?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array

```
test_array = [[4,3],[4,5],[6,7]]
```

I want to assign the last element of it to a variable

```
test = test_array.last #=> [6, 7]
```

And I want to change it

```
test[0] += 1
test #=> [7, 7]
```

Why has the last element of the array changed as well?

```
test_array #=> [[4, 3], [4, 5], [7, 7]]
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: No, you don't have a two-dimensional array, you have an array whose elements are arrays. There is a difference.

Comment: Could you point me to a document which explains this difference?

Comment: [`Matrix`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) from the standard library is sort of a two dimensional array. A 2D array is made up of rows and columns, you can access either one equally easily. You can work with the rows of your array-of-arrays but working by column is harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your multi-dimensional array (`test_array`) has a reference to the last element, so any changes you make to `test` will be seen in the `test_array`. If you don't desire this behavior, duplicate the last element before modifying it:

```
test_array = [[4,3],[4,5],[6,7]]
test = test_array.last.dup
# => [6, 7]
test[0] += 1
test
# => [7, 7]
test_array
# => [[4, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `test` holds a **reference** to the array `test_array.last`. If you modified the value of `test`, the value of `test_array.last` is modified as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can check to see what's happening; It's a technique I use periodically when I'm helping debug someone else's code and need to 'splain what is happening:

```
foo = [[1,2]]
bar = foo.first
```

`bar` contains a pointer AKA reference to the sub-array in `foo`. That means that the array at `foo.first` and `bar` are pointing to the same variable space in memory:

```
foo.first.object_id # => 70357558266700
bar.object_id # => 70357558266700
```

Because they're the same variable space, changing the array that `bar` points to, or changing the one that `foo.first` points to, will change the other one.

That can be useful if you understand what's going on, because if you have a big array and want to temporarily point to a deeply-nested element in it, you can assign a variable to point to it rather than use a long array accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Because that is the very array that you changed. There is no way to avoid that. You cannot change an array without changing it.